# How can I implement XOR Logic in JAVA

Tags: java

folks... Close to my previous question problem. So, in `XOR Gate` of a logical circuit, if `all` of input signals are `0` or `1` then the output is `0`; if the inputs's signals are mix such as `1110001111` then output is `1`; but if we have signals `0` and `X`(unknown signal), then the ouput is x; when `1` and `X` then the output should be `X`. I have a bug in the code of method because when, let's say `1111100001` signals are fed in the gate, I'm getting `0` instead of `1`. Could smb please help me? How should I handle if the inputs are `0000000` or `11111`? Note:`Signal.HI` is `1`, `Signal.LO` is `0`, `Signal.X` is `X`. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

```
   @Override
    public boolean propagate() 
    {
        Signal inputSignal;
        Signal tempSignal;
        Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();
        List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();
        Signal result = Signal.LO;

        for(int i = 1; i < inputs.size(); i++)
        {

            inputSignal = inputs.get(i).getSignal();
            tempSignal = inputs.get(0).getSignal();

            if(inputSignal == tempSignal)
                getOutput().setSignal(result);

            /*else if((inputSignal == Signal.LO) && (tempSignal == Signal.LO))
                getOutput().setSignal(result);*/

            else if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
            {
                result = inputSignal;
                getOutput().setSignal(result);
                break;
            }
            else            
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);
.............................................
```

Comment: The logic is quite simple. `if(input == output) return 0; else return 1;`.

Comment: @Nikolay Why do you think your current code should work? (Just wondering about your thought process)

Comment: Also, should `110` output `1`? If your description is accurate then it should, even though `11` outputs 0.

Comment: If you only have a list of `X`, result should be `LO`?

Answer (score 0):

Check you 'for-loop'. You are giving an output for every digit you scan. But what I get from your question detail, you want a single output after scanning all the signals.

```
Signal result = Signal.LO;
tempSignal = inputs.get(0).getSignal();

    for(int i = 1; i < inputs.size(); i++)
    {

        inputSignal = inputs.get(i).getSignal();


        if(inputSignal != tempSignal)
        {
              result = Signal.HI;
              break;
        }

        else if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
        {
            result = inputSignal;
            break;
        }
   }
getOutput().setSignal(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be systematic in the logic. I would formulate the solution like this:
 There is a list of `Signal` as inputs. You have to check the value of each `Signal` and build a *summary* (intermediate result) of what `Signal` have been processed so far.
In all cases, the process has to reach the end of the inputs, but when there is already one (or more) HI and one (or more) LO. In this case only, we know the output.
The *summary* can be easily design with just 3 `boolean` values that hold which kind of `Signal` have been processed.

I kept the different class methods you provided, but for the `Signal` I defined an `enum` which seems a good case and allows to use a `switch/case`:

```
enum Signal {
    LO(0), HI(1), X(-1);

    private int value;

    private Signal(int i) {
        this.value = i;
    }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

The `propagate()` method can be something like:

```
public boolean propagate() {
    // Summary
    boolean lo = false;
    boolean hi = false;
    boolean x = false;

    Iterator<Wire> iw = getInputs().iterator();
    // loop on wires. Stop if there is a LO and a HI
    while (iw.hasNext() && !(lo && hi)) {
        final Wire w = iw.next();
        switch (w.getSignal()) {
        case HI:
            hi = true;
            break;
        case LO:
            lo = true;
            break;
        case X:
            x = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Set the output
    if (hi && lo) {
        getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);
    } 
    else if (!lo && hi && x || lo && !hi && x) {
        getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);
    }
    else {
        getOutput().setSignal(Signal.LO);
    }
    // return true if all wires were checked
    return !iw.hasNext();
}
```

With the above method, results are:

> [LO, LO, LO] -> LO
>   [HI, HI, HI] -> LO
>   [LO, HI, HI] -> HI
>   [HI, X, HI] -> X
>   [LO, LO, X] -> X
>   [X, X, X] -> LO